# Is there a way to tell the Inventory button to stop flashing at me when I pickup new items?

Tags: diablo-iii

I pick up new items from almost every pack of mobs, so the little Inventory button at the bottom of the screen is almost constantly flashing to tell me I have new items.

Is there a way to stop it from flashing when I have new items in my bag? It's very obnoxious

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently there does not need to be a way to turn this off. I have found that by not picking up items as often, limiting my pickups to only blues and potions/gems that this is not as big of a factor.

And when I know that it's flashing because I picked something up I just quickly double-tab my inventory key to get rid of it. Only shows up for less than a second and it's not flashing any more. Not exactly the best use for APM, but a very small price to pay to get rid of the flash.

Answer (score 0):

It's indeed obnoxious, but it seems that right now there's no way of changing this. I've looked for it myself, including options to turn of the flashing when you get a new quest, but it doesn't seem to be possible at the moment.